# Prove that $\|(\delta,1)\|\geq \|(0,1)\|$ for all $\delta\in\mathbb{R}$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
**Prove that**
$$\forall\delta\in\mathbb{R},\; \|(\delta,1)\|\geq \|(0,1)\|.$$
Although, intuitively, it seems true, I can't find a way to prove it (it's an step for a bigger proof and I'm no certain the statement is actually true).

I've tried arriving at it through the triangle inequality, and other inequalities of the sort but ran out of ideas. Pleas help providing a proof or a good hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can fail for some norms.

Comment: How did you tried the triangle inequality?

Comment: Note that $\|(x,y)\|:=\max\{|x|,|x-y|\}$ is a norm

Comment: A generalization of a now deleted answer (special case): Statement is true if $\|\cdot\|=\|\cdot\|_p$.

$\displaystyle\delta\in \mathbb{R}\implies 0\leq |\delta|^p \implies |1|^p\leq |\delta|^p+|1|^p\implies \|(0,1)\|\leq \|(\delta,1)\|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the unit ball of a norm...

[image: pic]